# How many terms of the geometric sequence $2, 8, 32, 128,\dots $are required to give a sum of $174,762$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, solution-verification, geometric-progressions

> How many terms of the geometric sequence $2, 8, 32, 128,\dots $are required to give a sum of $174,762$?

**My attempt**

$a = 2$ (the first term)
$r = 4$ (the common ratio)
$S_n = 174,762$ (sum to $n$ terms)

Using the formula

$$S_n=a\bigg(\frac{r^n-1}{r-1}\bigg)$$

Therefore

\begin{align*}
S_n&=2\bigg(\frac{4^n-1}{4-1}\bigg)\\[5pt]
S_n&=174,762\\[5pt]
  4^n-1&= \frac{174,762\cdot3}{2} \\[5pt]
  4^n &= 262,144 \\[5pt]
n &= \log_4(262,144) \\[5pt]
n & =\frac{\ln(262,144)}{\ln(4)}\\[5pt]
n &= \frac{12.476...}{1.386...} \\[5pt]
n & = 9
\end{align*}

There 9 terms are required. Is there a better way go about this? Is this process succinct?

Comment: For some reason you had $4_n$ where I would expect $4^n.$

Comment: Another way to find this (with software assistance) is to convert the number to binary:  $ \ 174762_{10} \ = \ 101010101010101010_2 \ \  . $  The numbers in the geometric sequence occupy the odd-powers-of-2 positions and there are nine  $ \ 1$'s , so nine terms are required. (I offer this only as a comment, since I don't think it merits being an "answer".)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you reach
$$
4^n = 262,144
$$
I would proceed with arithmetic, not logarithms. You know
$$
4^5 = 2^{10} = 1,024
$$
so
$$
4^{10} = 2^{20} \approx 1,000,000
$$
is nearly four times too big. So   $4^9 = 262,144$ and you need $9$ terms.

Comment: A variation of this that a computer-science person might use is that $ \ 2^{20} \ $ is a "Meg" ( $ \ 1M \ $ ) , so $ \ 2^{17} \ $ (one-eighth of a Meg) would be the highest power of $ \ 2 \ $ smaller than $ \ 174762 \ . $  So we count the odd-positive-integer exponents up to $ \ 17 \ \  . $

Answer (score 0):

That is correct and it is a reasonable way to solve the problem. Of course you may add up the terms until you get to the answer due to fast growth of the terms.